# Linking SQL tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to link two of my tables together, however, I have no idea how to do this.
I have two tables, system and booking, here is the sql for the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `system` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
)

CREATE TABLE `booking` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `table_layout` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  'systemid' int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (systemid)
)
```

As you can see, both the tables share a field, 'systemid', this will be used to link the two together. I would like for the 'ID' number from 'systems' to enter the booking tables 'systemid'. I have no idea how to do this, I used this code, to retrieve the Systems 'ID'.

BUTTON.INC.PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'calendardatabase.inc.php';

    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['datepicker']);
    $time = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['time']);
    $u_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['u_id']);

        if (empty($time) || empty($date)) {
header("Location: ../loginsystem/time=empty.html");
    exit();
    } else {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO system (date, time, user_id) VALUES ('$date', '$time', '$u_id');";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <br></br>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<center><h4>Please Select A Table: </h4></center>
    <center>
<section class="main-container">
<div class="main-wrapper"> 
<form class="calendar-form" action="booking.inc.php" method="POST">


      <center><h4>The Restaurants Layout: </h4></center>
      <br></br>
<img class= "img-tablelayout" src="tables.png" alt="">
    <br></br>

  <div class="main-wrapper"> 
  <br></br>
  <?php

echo 'For the selected time: '; echo $time;
echo ' & the selected date: '; echo $date;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
?>

   <p>Please select an available table: <select name="table_layout">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="one"> <?php

    $sql = "SELECT system.date, system.time, booking.table_layout FROM system JOIN booking ON system.id= booking.id WHERE system.time = '$time'  AND system.date='$date' AND booking.table_layout = 'one'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
echo '';
    }
    if ($resultCheck == 0) {
echo 'Booth One: available';
    }   


?>
    </option>
    <option value="two"> <?php

    $sql = "SELECT system.date, system.time, booking.table_layout FROM system JOIN booking ON system.id= booking.id WHERE system.time = '$time'  AND system.date='$date' AND booking.table_layout = 'two'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
echo '';
    }
    if ($resultCheck == 0) {
echo 'Booth Two: available';
    }   


?> </option>

   </p> </select>

        <input type="hidden" name="u_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['u_id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_id" value="<?php ['last_id']; ?>">



    <button type="send" name="send">Next</button>   


</form>
```

BOOKING.INC.PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();
 ?>
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

    include_once 'calendardatabase.inc.php';

    $table_layout = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['table_layout']);
    $u_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['u_id']);
    $last_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last_id']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO booking (table_layout, user_id, systemid) VALUES ('$table_layout','$u_id', '$last_id');";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
} var_dump($_POST) 

?>
```

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` would work but you don't have an AI'd column, so you'll need to ALTER those.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Hello! It does work in retriving the system table 'ID', however, the system 'ID' doesnt enter my booking 'systemid', please see the latest code I've included. Thank you

Comment: you need to ALTER the respective column name(s) to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`'ed. Look at the manual https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php --- *The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query (usually INSERT) on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If no INSERT or UPDATE statements were sent via this connection, or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.*

Comment: There's no `systemid` column in the `booking` table.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Okay, so I have to auto increment the systemid?

Comment: yes, that's what needs to be done. There risks to have other modifications done as @Barmar stated.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It said theres an error as there can only be one autoincrement key, and I made that the 'id

Comment: @aei The foreign key doesn't need to be auto-increment, the ID that it references does.

Comment: @Barmar I've done that already, so now what do I do?

Comment: After you insert into `system`, you use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID that was assigned, and use that as the value of `system` when you insert into `booking`.

Comment: @Barmar It doesnt seem to be working. Where am I meant to put LAST_INSERT_ID()?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="u_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['u_id']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="last_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['last_id']; ?>">  
  
  
  
    <button type="send" name="send">Next</button>  Is this correct?

Comment: This all assumes you're doing both inserts in the same script, i.e. you want to use the new system ID immediately after you insert it.

Comment: In your script, `$last_id` serves this purpose of passing the new ID from one script to the next.

Answer (score 1):

You have your column names and variable names interchanged in your second script. It should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO booking (table_layout, user_id, systemid) VALUES ('$table_layout','$u_id', '$last_id');";
```

You also should learn to use prepared queries with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`, to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Hello, that still did not seem to enter the id number into it :/ I cant seem to see any other mistakes than what you just suggested!

Comment: Are you seeing the correct ID in the `Last inserted ID is` message?

Comment: yes I am seeing the correct ID from the systems table, but the booking table is just showing '0' for 'systemid' when it should be 40 etc

Comment: where should i put this?

Comment: array(4) { ["table_layout"]=> string(7) "fifteen" ["u_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["last_id"]=> string(128) "
Notice: Undefined index: last_id in E:\Xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\button.inc.php on line 397
" ["send"]=> string(0) "" } fifteen

Comment: You defined `$last_id`, but never did `$_SESSION['last_id'] = $last_id;`

Comment: where should i put $_SESSION['last_id'] = $last_id; ?

Comment: Why do you need this in a session variable? Just use `$last_id` in the hidden input.

Comment: And if you use a session variable, you don't need to put it into a hidden input.

Comment: I got rid of the session variable, and now have this: array(4) { ["table_layout"]=> string(8) "fourteen" ["u_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["last_id"]=> string(135) "
Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\Xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\button.inc.php on line 397
Array" ["send"]=> string(0) "" } fourteen

Comment: You got that from `<?php echo $last_id; ?>`?

Comment: No, from <input type="hidden" name="last_id" value="<?php echo ['last_id']; ?>">

Comment: From <?php echo $last_id; ?>?, I get: Notice: Undefined index: last_id in E:\Xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\booking.inc.php on line 12
array(3) { ["table_layout"]=> string(7) "sixteen" ["u_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["send"]=> string(0) "" } sixteen /// booking.inc is the second script

Comment: That makes no sense. You can't get an `Undefined index` error when you write an ordinary variable instead of an array.

Comment: I'm running out of hope and ideas! How do I define it in the second script?

Comment: You need to figure out what you're doing wrong in the FIRST script that's preventing it from putting the correct value of `$last_id` in the hidden input.

Comment: Add the latest version of the two scripts to the end of the question.

Comment: I changed  <input type="hidden" name="last_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['last _id']; ?>"> INTO:
<input type="hidden" name="last_id" value="<?php ['last_id']; ?>">, AND NOW I GET: array(4) { ["table_layout"]=> string(7) "fifteen" ["u_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["last_id"]=> string(0) "" ["send"]=> string(0) "" } So no error messages, but nothings being entered inside last_id

Comment: You weren't supposed to remove the original scripts, just add the updated version. Readers need to be able to see what the original problem was, so that the answers make sense.

Comment: `<?php ['last_id']; ?>` should be `<?php echo $last_id; ?>` --  you seem to have gotten so frustrated that you're messing up basic syntax. I suggest you take a breath, stop rushing, and think about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this code you wrote but this not correct

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO booking (table_layout, user_id, last_id) VALUES ('$table_layout','$u_id', '$systemid');";
```

you should replace

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO booking (table_layout, user_id, systemid) VALUES ('$table_layout','$u_id', '$last_id');";
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but the previous answer spotted that out already! My sql still does not seem to be working

Comment: the system 'ID' does not seem to be entering my booking 'systemid'

Comment: CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);